# How to get URL content using C# from silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, url

I used below code to get content of a given URL from my silverlightlight application but I got the error :

> "An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.dll but was not handled in user code"

I checked elevated trust in my silverlight application. 
but nothing changed!

```
private void StartWebRequest(string url)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest),request);
}

 private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
   HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to put a crossdomain xml file in  root directory of hosted service which is explained [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the mentioned error I changed FinishWebRequest function as:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(result) ;
}
```

can anybody says what happend?